# Adding two byte arrays in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte

I'd like to combine two byte arrays which represent images (so they're the same size) into a third byte array which will be the average of the two starting images. Here's the code I'm trying at the moment:

```
        byte[] facemash = new byte[data1.length];

        for (int i=0; i < data1.length; ++i){
            facemash[i] = ((data1[i]/2)+(data2[i]/2));
        }
```

What I'm getting in Eclipse is an error telling me 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte.' Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
facemash[i] = (byte)((byte)(data1[i]/2)+(byte)(data2[i]/2));
```

Answer (score 1):

java converts bytes to ints in arithmetic ops. Just cast the result to (byte) since you know it can't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
facemash[i] = (byte)((data1[i]/2)+(data2[i]/2));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still giving me the same error (I've already declared data1 and data2 as bytes in the code)

Comment: I changed my answer, then it should be ok.